# How to duplicate the Category Tree in Shopware 6 for a new sales channel?

Tags: content-management-system, shopware

We want to open a shop in a new sales channel with a different, but similar category structure.

Is there a built-in or programatic way to duplicate a root category an all it's children so we can assign it to a new sales channel and start translating and modifying?

Comment: maybe you can do it youself using the api?

Comment: Don't see an easy way, do you?
But there is a issue in the backlog https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-11360